# Serial to USB adapter for thermal receipt printer PC won't recognize device

Tags: windows-7, usb, printing, printer

I have a WASP RP-300 Thermal Receipt Printer and purchased a Serial to USB adapter for a Windows 7 PC. It only appears to register the adapter and when it installed it stated, "Your Device is Ready to USE (USB Printing Support -Ready to use, No Printer Attached -Ready to use)", but the printer is nowhere to be found. What do I need to do?[Dialog after installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNAF7.jpg)

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit PC

Comment: *"but the printer is nowhere to be found."* -- Because the printer is a "remote" device that is connected to the PC by a serial link.  You need to access the printer through the COM port (after both ends of the serial link are properly configured).  This isn't plug'n'play equipment.   IOW you're going to have to read some documentation.

Comment: Sorry but the only documentation for the adapter is a piece of paper with an image of computer with the printer telling me to connect the to.  When I contacted the manufacturer they said that it was Plug n Play and other than that weren't any help.  It is an older printer but I can't find any documentation for the printer about this kind of situation of Serial to USB.  Any documentation you could recommend for properly configuring this printer?